# C++ How to make a clock in Win32 Console Application without stopping application?

Tags: c++, clock

if i try loop in main function => stopping everything(even my mouse too)

how to make a changeable string without stopping application in console application?

```
int status;
string str;
while (true)
{
    if (status != 1)
    {
        str = "i'm sleeping now";
    }
    else if (status == 1)
    {
        str = "i'm ready for working!";
    }
    cout << str;
}
```

Comment: Why would a clock need to loop? Use a timer, set to fire every second, or every minute. Update the clock's display when the timer fires. Post actual code if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in one place in the console, you'll need some OS-specific stuff like cursor positioning. You won't if you simply want to enter a new line with new time e.g. every minute.

The actual timing of the output can be done in a multitude of ways, but nearly all of them assume that the program holds its own event loop (which is in contrast to typical console applications blocking on input). It can be done in console, just requires a more complicated setup.

If you don't need input at all, then you can busy wait or just sleep until the time comes. It all depends on what your program is supposed to do *besides* outputting time.

Alternatively, simply build a non-console app, where it becomes much more straightforward.

Comment: Hah! I've never imagined that things might be "much more straightforward" in a non-console app than a console app. I'm not even sure that's true. The windowing system *requires* that you have an event loop, but doesn't make it any simpler or more straightforward.

Comment: @CodyGray Just the fact that you get more ways to interact with the user gives you more tools to work with. Having more tools maybe isn't simpler for a beginner, but serves someone experienced way better. Besides, there are frameworks that abstract the OS-specific event loop for you, quite possibly leaving you with less code in the end.